# HTML Linked Images Issues

Tags: html, image, web, hyperlink

When working on an HTML email signature, I wrote basic HTML for four linked images.

```
<a href="http://www.dwightfund1.com">
<img src="https://dwight.app.box.com/representation/file_version_28131628265/image_2048/1.png?shared_name=x116s7oza2gydr9tmlqgv7oad349y885" width="40" height="40" alt="capture"/>
</a>
<a href="http://www.dwightfund2.com">
<img src="https://dwight.app.box.com/representation/file_version_28131627701/image_2048/1.png?shared_name=97bbaqds6wg6up5ip12a5t55lts7mnd4" width="40" height="40" alt="capture" border="0">
</a>
<a href="http://www.dwightfund3.com">
<img src="https://dwight.app.box.com/representation/file_version_28131629073/image_2048/1.png?shared_name=w9ucedcax4fmcw3lelwl9rhgdbhyqvo4" width="40" height="40" alt="capture"/>
</a>
<a href="http://www.dwightfund4.com">
<img src="https://dwight.app.box.com/representation/file_version_28131628619/image_2048/1.png?shared_name=a3t36efnz0cs3kmcza2an0wehrnczu48" width="40" height="40" alt="capture"/>
</a>
```

When I view the code in my browser these weird lines appear next to the images like below:
[image]

Why are these lines there any how can I remove them?

Comment: Seems to be border.. Put border=0 That might solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be the link's default `text-decoration: underline` in the spaces between the images.

If this is for an E-Mail client (that don't support CSS style sheets), you'll probably have to do something like

```
<a style="text-decoration: none" href="http://www.dwightfund4.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

This border is meant to inform users that the image is a link.

```
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}

img{
  border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it with color of a element:

http://codepen.io/fedojo/pen/NqGKNX

for example :`<a href="http://www.dwightfund1.com" style="color: #fff">`

Comment: You should request for the associated CSS file also, who know may be that is creating an issue. If no external CSS is associated, then your answer holds good